# Wrong BindingHandler being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am having a very strange issue where the wrong binding handler is being called when a dropdown changes. I am using Knockout 3.1 with jQuery 1.9.1. We have a set of cascading dropdowns to make it easier to locate an employee.

Here is what happens. As the page loads, each handler is called as expected. When I change the value in `#AssignedDepartment` the `serviceAreaSelect` handler is called, not `departmentSelect` as expected. `departmentSelect` isn't called at all which needs to be called to properly fill the `#AssignedServiceAreaName` dropdown. However when I make a change to `#AssignedServiceAreaName`, `serviceAreaSelect` is called and works as expected.

What might be going on here? This code worked fine in Knockout 2.x.

Here is two of the three handlers for the series of three cascading dropdowns.

```
// Department Selected
ko.bindingHandlers.departmentSelect = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, vm) {
        var el = $(element).find("option:selected");
        console.log("Department Selected: ", el.val());
        if (el.length > 0) {
            vm.deptName(el.text());
            $.get('/customerservice/jsonproxy/servicearealist', { deptID: el.val() }, function (response) { vm.ServiceArea(response); }, 'json');
        }
    }
}

// Service Area Selected
ko.bindingHandlers.serviceAreaSelect = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, vm) {
        var el = $(element).find("option:selected");
        console.log("Service Area Selected: ", el.val());
        if (el.length > 0) {
            vm.ServiceAreaName(el.text());
            $.get('/customerservice/jsonproxy/employeelist', { deptID: vm.deptID, serviceAreaID: el.val() }, function (response) {
                vm.EmployeeList(response[0].Employees);
                vm.EmployeeList.unshift({ EmployeeName: "None Assigned", EmployeeID: "" });
            }, 'json');

        }
    }
};
```

Here is the HTML.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span4">

    @Html.MyLabelFor(m => m.Department, new { @class = "control-label" })

    <select class="span12" id="AssignedDepartment" name="AssignedDepartment" 
        data-bind="options: dept, optionsCaption: 'Select a department', optionsValue: function (item) { return item.DepartmentID }, optionsText: function (item) { return item.DepartmentName; }, value: deptID, departmentSelect: deptID"></select>
    <span data-bind="text: deptID"></span><span data-bind="    text: deptName"></span>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Department, new { data_bind = "value: deptName" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DepartmentCode, new { data_bind = "value: deptID" })

</div>
<div class="span4">

    @Html.MyLabelFor(m => m.ServiceArea, new { @class = "control-label" })

    <select class="span12" id="AssignedServiceAreaName" name="AssignedServiceArea" data-bind="options: ServiceArea, optionsCaption: 'Select a Service Area', optionsValue: function (item) { return item.ServiceAreaID; }, optionsText: function (item) { return item.ServiceAreaName; }, value: ServiceAreaID, serviceAreaSelect: ServiceAreaID"></select>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ServiceArea, new { @data_bind = "value: ServiceAreaName" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ServiceAreaCode, new { @data_bind = "value: ServiceAreaID" })
    @*<span data-bind="text: ServiceAreaID"></span><span data-bind="    text: ServiceAreaName"></span>*@

</div>
<div class="span4">

    @Html.MyLabelFor(m => m.Employee, new { @class = "control-label" })

    <select class="span12" id="AssignedEmployee" name="AssignedEmployee" data-bind="options: EmployeeList, optionsCaption: 'None Assigned', optionsValue: function (item) { return item.EmployeeID; }, optionsText: function (item) { return item.EmployeeName; }, value: EmployeeID, employeeSelect: EmployeeID"></select>
    @*<span data-bind="text: EmployeeID"></span><span data-bind="    text: EmployeeName"></span>*@
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employee, new { data_bind = "value: EmployeeName" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeID, new { data_bind = "value: EmployeeID" })

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In KO 3.0 the bindings are now refreshed individually: http://knockoutjs.com/upgrade-notes/v3.0.0.html#bindings-are-now-refreshed-independently maybe this is also causing your problem.

Comment: It appears like I only have two bindings on the field. One would be the value, the second being the handler.

Comment: Is there an option to move binding logic to subscribers?

Comment: I am not sure it is as we are trying to fill pull both the value and the text from the drop down list. It does work (I just tried it), but how would I pull the text from the selected dropdown item?

Comment: I guess `self.deptName($('#AssignedDepartment option:selected').text());` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `update` callback is designed to redraw the DOM in respond of model changes, not a place `to update model when DOM changes` (as your code implies).

Only read model's value in `update` callback in order to update DOM, never mutate model inside `update` callback.

The `value` binding (value: deptID) syncs the DOM with the model(deptID), you don't need another bindingHandler.

What you want is just `do something when model changes`.

1. get rid of `ko.bindingHandlers.departmentSelect` and
   `ko.bindingHandlers.serviceAreaSelect` and
   `ko.bindingHandlers.employeeSelect`
2. remove binding
   `departmentSelect: deptID`, `serviceAreaSelect: ServiceAreaID` and
   `employeeSelect: EmployeeID`.
3. Do the logic in your model as your own answer suggested.

Yes, there is part of you code still not `ko` style, which is `self.deptName($('#AssignedDepartment option:selected').text())`.

Ideally in ko app, all DOM manipulation should be hidden inside bindingHandler's `init` and `update` callbacks.

There are two ways to fix it:

A) update deptName automatically.

```
self.deptID.subscribe(function (val) {
    if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
        $.get('/customerservice/jsonproxy/servicearealist', { deptID: val }, function (response) {
            self.ServiceArea(response);
            if (response.length === 1) {
                self.ServiceAreaID(response[0].ServiceAreaID);
            }
        }, 'json');
    }
});

// deptName is another representation of deptID
self.deptName = ko.computed(function() {
    // I don't know whether your dept is observableArray or plain array
    var depts = ko.unwrap(self.dept);
    var currentOne = ko.utils.arrayFirst(depts, function(d) {
        return d.DepartmentID == self.deptID();
    });
    return currentOne && currentOne.DepartmentName;
});
```

B) change the model, don't capture deptID, capture the whole deptSelected object.

```
//self.deptID = ko.observable();    
self.deptSelected = ko.observable();
self.deptSelected.subscribe(function (newDept) { /* ajax */ });

// optionsText: 'DepartmentName' is enough, no need a mapping function.
<select class="span12" id="AssignedDepartment" name="AssignedDepartment" 
    data-bind="options: dept, optionsCaption: 'Select a department',
               optionsText: 'DepartmentName', value: deptSelected"></select>
<!-- ko with: deptSelected -->
    <span data-bind="text: DepartmentID"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: DepartmentName"></span>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Department, new { data_bind = "value: DepartmentName" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DepartmentCode, new { data_bind = "value: DepartmentID" })
<!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a work-around working. I am doing a subscribe:

```
self.deptID.subscribe(function (val) {
    if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
        $.get('/customerservice/jsonproxy/servicearealist', { deptID: val }, function (response) {
            self.ServiceArea(response);
            if (response.length === 1) {
                self.ServiceAreaID(response[0].ServiceAreaID);
            }
        }, 'json');
        self.deptName($('#AssignedDepartment option:selected').text());
    }
});

self.ServiceAreaID.subscribe(function (val) {
    if (val !== undefined && val !== null) {
        $.get('/customerservice/jsonproxy/employeelist', { deptID: self.deptID, serviceAreaID: val }, function (response) {
            self.EmployeeList(response[0].Employees);
            self.EmployeeList.remove({ EmployeeName: "None Assigned", EmployeeID: "" });
            self.ServiceAreaName($('#AssignedServiceAreaName option:selected').text());
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

It might not be 100% knockout anymore, but this is the only way I could make it work.